# jQuery Modal and FancySelect Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have the `jQuery FancySelect` plugin installed. Works fine. Now I am trying to call it in a modal popup, but it does not work. This is the code in the parent window:

```
<script src="/js/fancySelect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancyselect').fancySelect();
    var repoName    = 'fancyselect'
    var menu        = $('#top').find('menu');
    function positionMenuArrow() {
        var current = menu.find('.current');
        menu.find('.arrow').css('left', current.offset().left + (current.outerWidth() / 2));
    }
    $(window).on('resize', positionMenuArrow);
    menu.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        var el          = $(this),
        href            = el.attr('href'),
        currentSection  = $('#main').find('.current');
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.find('.current').removeClass('current');
        el.addClass('current');
        positionMenuArrow();
        if (currentSection.length) {
            currentSection.fadeOut(300).promise().done(function() {
                $(href).addClass('current').fadeIn(300);
            });
        }
        else {
            $(href).addClass('current').fadeIn(300);
        }
    });
    menu.find('a:first').trigger('click')
});
</script>
```

Adding `class="fancyselect"` to any select in the parent works. However, does not work if added to `modal popup select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just speculating here as you did not show the **HTML** or the **JS** logic that is dealing with the popup creation. Are the elements where you wan to apply the FancySelect method, from the popup plugin already on the page when you call the:

```
$('.fancyselect').fancySelect();
```

?

If the elements are added after the page load they won't be picked up by that statement. When displaying the popup you would do somehting like

```
$('#popupcontainer .fancyselect').fancySelect();
```

So they will all the required code will be applied on that elements as well.

**Update:**

Following the update give in your original post, you can add something like: [not tested]

```
onLoad: function() { 
    var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap"); 
    $(wrap).find('.fancyselect').fancySelect();         
}
```

This should be triggered after the popup has been populated.

Comment: The modal is an overlay using the following inline JS:

    <div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
    <div class="contentWrap"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/rocketscript">
    $(function() {
     $("a[rel]").overlay({
      mask:  '#EAEAEA',
      effect:  'apple',
      api:  true,
      onBeforeLoad: function() {
       var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
       wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
      }
     });
    });
    </script>

This is in the footer after the FancySelect code (which is in header).